# Double visual studio code?

Tags: applications

[image: Double Visual studio code applications]

Help i got 2 visual studio code applications icons and i cannot find a fix please help!

Comment: Did you install it via Flatpak or apt?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would have two icons, but you could hide one using AppEditor (https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor)

Comment: This is a great app for managing your application menu. If you choose to install it install the version that is in the AppCenter and not flathub.org as the latter will not be able to view system apps. You can also use this tool to view the "Command Line" script to ensure that you don't have multiple versions of an app installed in different locations (e.g. apt and flathub).